# Was ist die Etymologie von "Fegefeuer"

Tags: etymology

Ich weiß, was es auf Englisch bedeutet, aber ich will wissen, warum es auf Deutsch so heißt, besonders "Fege-".

Comment: https://dwds.de/wb/Fegefeuer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Das Wort Fegefeuer ist ein ebenso deutsches wie katholisches Wort. Es ist eine direkte Lehnübersetzung aus diesem Milieu:

> **[Herkunft](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Fegefeuer):**
>   mittelhochdeutsch *vegeviur*, Lehnübersetzung von kirchenlateinisch *pūrgātiōnis ignis* → la „Feuer der Reinigung“
>   strukturell: Determinativkompositum aus dem Stamm des Verbs fegen und dem Substantiv Feuer mit dem Gleitlaut -e-

Fegen als Wortbestandteil ist also mit Reinigung gleichzusetzen. Vergleiche auch das niederländische [Vagevuur](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vagevuur).

> **[Etymologie](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Fegefeuer)**
>   fegen · Fegefeuer
>   fegen Vb. ‘mit dem Besen reinigen, kehren’, südd. ‘naß reinigen, wischen’ ahd. *fegōn* ‘säubern, putzen’ (10. Jh.), mhd. vegen ‘kehren, reinigen, putzen’, asächs. *fegon*, mnd. *vēgen*, mnl. *vēghen*, nl. *vegen*, ablautend mnl. *vāghen*, nl. *(weg)vagen,* anord. *fāga* ‘reinigen, glänzend machen, schmücken’ sowie die unter *↗fair* (s. d.) genannten germ. Formen können mit lit. *puõšti* ‘schmücken, putzen’, lett. post ‘schmücken’ auf eine Wurzel ie. **pek̑-* ‘hübsch machen, aufgeräumt oder vergnügt sein’ zurückgeführt werden, zu der sich vielleicht auch (mit grammatischem Wechsel) ahd. *gifehan* ‘sich freuen, Freude äußern’ (9. Jh.), aengl. *(ge)fēon* ‘froh sein’ stellen läßt. Fegefeuer n. wörtlich ‘reinigendes Feuer’, nach katholischer Glaubenslehre ‘Läuterungsort der Verstorbenen’, mhd. *vegeviur*, Übersetzung von kirchenlat. *pūrgātōrius (pūrgātiōnis) ignis* (vgl. lat. *pūrgāre* ‘reinigen, sühnen’, *pūrus* ‘rein, lauter’).

Answer (score 1):

Die lateinische Bezeichnung für das Fegefeuer ist Ignis purgatorius bzw Purgatorium. Während Purgatorium meist direkt mit Fegefeuer übersetzt wird kann man Ignis purgatorius wörtlich als reinigendes Feuer übersetzen.

Fege als solches hat die Bedeutung von "Reinigung" oder "Reinigung einer Sache" (siehe [DWB](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/call_wbgui_py_from_form?sigle=DWB&mode=Volltextsuche&hitlist=&lemmapattern=&patternlist=&lemid=GF01805) und [hier](https://books.google.de/books?id=HM0UAAAAYAAJ&lpg=PA374&ots=1yhBzku8A7&dq=fege%20reinigung&hl=de&pg=PA373#v=onepage&q=fege%20reinigung&f=false))

Insofern ist es auch hier ein "Reinigendes Feuer".